# React type error with refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I have a problem with the ref:

```
<form className="form" onSubmit={(e)=> e.preventDefault() }>
  <InputInForm name="number" ref="shareNumder" id="shareNumder" /> 
  <Button className="count" value="count" onClick={this.result} />
</form>

result(e)
{
  let sharePric2e = this.refs.sharePrice.value.replace(/ /g, '');
  console.log(sharePric2e);
}
```

and function which gets the ref:

```
function InputInForm(props) {
return (
    <div className="inputs">
        <span className="titleInput">{props.name}</span>
        <input type="text"  id={props.id} ref={props.ref} className="formBlock" placeholder="Введите значение"/>
    </div>
);
}

export default InputInForm;
```

And I got an error "TypeError: this.refs.sharePrice is null".
How I can get value of input using ref ?

Comment: You shouldn't be using refs for form inputs. Read these sections of the docs to learn how to implement this kind of thing: [Forms](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [Thinking in React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: General rule - 99.99% of the time, refs are not the right solution to the problem. They are explicitly stated in the docs as being an escape hatch for 'cases where you need to imperatively modify a child outside of the typical dataflow'. I literally never had to use them, and every time I've been tempted, there's always been a better way.

Comment: Even if you want to use refs, you have to pass ref="sharePrice"